# Find total minutes without the overlapping times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to find total number of minutes without the overlapping minutes. Below is sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE tim (starttime DATETIME, endtime DATETIME) 
INSERT INTO tim 
VALUES 
('2022-01-3 12:03:00.000',  '2022-01-3 12:20:00.000'),  
('2022-01-3 12:01:00.000',  '2022-01-3 12:06:00.000'),  
('2022-01-3 03:01:00.000',  '2022-01-3 03:06:00.000'),  
('2022-01-3 01:00:00.000',  '2022-01-3 01:26:00.000'),
('2022-01-3 01:03:00.000',  '2022-01-3 01:28:00.000'), 
('2022-01-3 01:05:00.000',  '2022-01-3 01:30:07.000')
```

When I run this line of query to select the time differences in the table, I get 17, 5, 5, 30 and 25 for the 5 consecutive rows (output is on the table below).

```
SELECT starttime, endtime, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,starttime, endtime) Diff FROM tim
```

| starttime | endtime | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-3 12:03:00.000 | 2022-01-3 12:20:00.000 | 17 |
| 2022-01-3 12:01:00.000 | 2022-01-3 12:06:00.000 | 5 |
| 2022-01-3 03:01:00.000 | 2022-01-3 03:06:00.000 | 5 |
| 2022-01-3 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-3 01:30:00.000 | 30 |
| 2022-01-3 01:03:00.000 | 2022-01-3 01:28:00.000 | 25 |
| 2022-01-3 01:05:00.000 | 2022-01-3 01:30:07.000 | 25 |

However, since the first two rows (row 1 and 2) and the last two rows (row 4 and 5) are overlapping, I would like to have the below records instead:
Expected output:

| starttime | endtime | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-3 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-3 01:30:07.000 | 30 |
| 2022-01-3 03:01:00.000 | 2022-01-3 03:06:00.000 | 5 |
| 2022-01-3 12:01:00.000 | 2022-01-3 12:20:00.000 | 19 |

I was trying to apply
LAG(starttime) over (order by starttime) and
LEAD (starttime) over (order by starttime)
, but they couldn't get it done for me consistently.

Any guide is appreciated.

Comment: Having start-end values that are not minute boundaries may also be an issue, Given the endtime 2022-01-3 01:30:07 above, what if another record had a start time = 2022-01-3 01:30:45? Are they considered overlapping? What about if the values were reversed? You might need to normalize the data before processing and make sure the edge cases are well defined.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? I have some ideas, but it would take some time to formulate. My suggested approach would be to (1) Order the rows by startTime. (2) Calculate a running max or endTime. (3) Flag any records where startTime >running max-endTime on the prior row. (4) For each flagged row, retrieve the running max-endTime for the record preceding the next flagged row. (5) Calculate the difference in minutes. This would likely involve a temp table containing ordered and numbered data in which the additional data could be built up.

Comment: @TN yes. I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a lag/lead implementation that gives your desired results, does the following work for you?

```
with t as (
  select starttime,
    case when Lag(endtime) over (order by starttime) > starttime then 0 else 1 end UseStart,
    case when endtime < Lead(starttime) over(order by starttime) 
        then endtime 
      else Lead(endtime,1,endtime) over (order by starttime) 
    end endtime
 from tim
)
select starttime, endtime, DateDiff(minute,starttime, endtime) Diff 
from t
where UseStart=1
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6688dc45929c72f98d322c91309e1430)

Comment: The above might need some tweaking. I'm getting a few odd results if I add the following to the mix:
`,('2022-01-05 01:00',  '2022-01-05 01:05')
,('2022-01-05 01:05',  '2022-01-05 01:10')
,('2022-01-05 01:06',  '2022-01-05 01:08')
,('2022-01-05 01:07',  '2022-01-05 01:09')
,('2022-01-05 02:00',  '2022-01-05 02:09')
,('2022-01-05 02:01',  '2022-01-05 02:08')
,('2022-01-05 02:02',  '2022-01-05 02:07')
,('2022-01-05 02:03',  '2022-01-05 02:06')
,('2022-01-05 02:04',  '2022-01-05 02:05')`

Comment: Yes @Stu. I have modified the dataset to add an additional row. The one you drafted functions well when the overlapping rows constitutes 2 rows. When they're >=3, it takes whatever is at the 2nd row. For example, in the above dataset, it gives 28, while it should 30. That was what I mean, it wasn't consistent when I introduce lag/lead.

Answer (score -1):

First, select every starttime you want. Use joins or subqueries to find if the starttime appears between the starttime and endtime in a different row or not. If it does, filter the current row out.

Second, find the best endtime for each starttime. Use a subquery to find all rows where the current row's starttime is between that starttime and endtime. Then select the latest (greatest) endtime.